# How to change directory for launching `npx folio`

Tags: playwright

I want to start using Microsoft Playwright for my web application. When running `npx folio` to start my tests its targeting this folder by default `C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\firefox-1225\firefox\firefox.exe` but that is not where I want it to target.

It results in an error when running `npx folio` because firefox.exe does not exist in that directory

```
C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\firefox-1225\firefox\firefox.exe does not exist...
```

**How do I get pass this?**

Comment: Why don't you want to use that?

Comment: The programs inside there can't run because of security restrictions. Therefore I need to maintain Playwright in an admin directory

Comment: Do you want to run your Playwright tests with a custom executable path, so you can move the installed firefox e.g. into another folder?
And what is the exact error, because the thing what you shared is not an error.

Comment: @MaxSchmitt That is exactly what I want. Thanks for your input regarding clearifying the error. I don't remember the exact wording but I did make an edit to the question. I did manage to solve this by using an environment variable when installing playwright. I'll update the question in a few days.